# How do I create a button that brings you to the Google Maps app at a specific location?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a simple android button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTakeMeThere"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:text="Take me there!"
    ...
/>
```

My app contains some information inside my activity about a place the user should go, stored as latitude and longitude.

I would like this button to bring the user to the Google maps app and go to that location.

How do I do this?

So far I've added an onclick listener to the button (I'm using Kotlin)

```
var latitude, longitude: Float;

btnTakeMeThere.setOnClickListener {

}
```

Comment: Might want to look at these intents. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:[lat],[long]?z=17[zoom]&q=[text]");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```